# How to use Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType (the non-obsolete version) to cast from Com Object to Outlook Type

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, com

I have a piece of code that works well for me using an obsolete function. I'll strip down to minimal parts:

```
private dynamic pSentFolderItems; //will reference the Items of an Outlook Folder 

public void WatchEmail2(object app, string emailID)
{
    pApp = app; //this is actually an Outlook Application instance
    //below reference to the Items object comes back as ComObject
    pSentFolderItems = pApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(5).Items;

    //get the type through Reflection on the instance
    Type olItemsType = pApp.GetType().Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemsClass", false, true);

    //pSentFolderItems = Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(pSentFolderItems, olItemsType);
    //above works every time but is marked Obsolete!!
    //http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=296519

    //I'm struggling to implement the generic version of the CreateWrapperOfType method, as errors occur
    //and I cannot input the type parameters without errors
    pSentFolderItems = Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType<ShouldBeComObjectType, ShouldBeOlItemsType>(pSentFolderItems);

    //.....rest of code........
}
```

Here is VB Code:

```
Public Class OVBO
    Private pApp As Object
    Public pMailId As String = ""
    Public itemSent As Boolean = False  'change to a map?
    Public itemWatching As Boolean = False

    Public pSentFolderItems As Object

    Public Sub WatchEmail2(app As Object, emailID As String)
        pMailId = emailID
        pApp = app

        If Not itemWatching Then
            pSentFolderItems = pApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(5).Items

            Dim olType As Type = pApp.GetType().Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemsClass", False, True)
            Dim myFlags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic
            Dim evt As EventInfo = olType.GetEvent("ItemAdd", myFlags)
            Dim evtHandlerType As Type = evt.EventHandlerType

            Dim finalD As [Delegate] = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(evtHandlerType, Me, "MailSent2")
            Dim addHandlerArgs() As Object = {finalD}

            'The below works to return an Items Object(from a ComObject) that can be passed to the method handler invocation
            pSentFolderItems = Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(pSentFolderItems, olType)
            'The above is obsolete, and am struggling to work with the non-obsolete method at [MSDN][1]

            Dim miAddHandler As MethodInfo = evt.GetAddMethod()
            miAddHandler.Invoke(pSentFolderItems, addHandlerArgs)

            itemWatching = True
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("Watching {0}", emailID)
    End Sub

    'rest of class
End Class
```

Please note there are no references to the Outlook dll, and no Interop references.

So I am wondering if anyone can help translate the obsolete method call into the new way.

Comment: Try not to use tags that aren't relevant; This was not a `vb.net` question

Comment: Have you tried `pSentFolderItems = Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(pSentFolderItems);`?

Comment: How did this happen?  Was this originally written before C# supported the *dynamic* keyword?  No need to wrap to keep the C# binder happy.  Also note that this code can only work when the caller uses early binding with the interop library, since you have it available you might as well use it.

Comment: I hear you @Martin but a VB programmer may know the answer, and I honestly have the code in VB. The C# was just a translation for a bigger audience.

Comment: @Martin, I tried but cannot infer type parameters

Comment: @HansPassant, i was afraid you'd say that(use early binding) judging from your other answers on this topic. I have the real code in VB - same problem. It is an attempt to dynamically invoke a handler on the Items object. God knows early binding makes all the pain go away. But the idea is to not rely on any refencing to the Outlook Dll, only to know that we can operate on outlook once it is installed in any version on the machine

Comment: No *dynamic* keyword in vb.net, you're not exactly helping us to help you.  I'll reiterate, this code can only work when the caller does in fact reference the interop library.  So the feature you thought you had did not actually exist.  That this never caused a problem is not unusual at all.

Comment: @HansPassant pApp is dynamic in C# here too. I realise that the VB has no dynamic. I will update the question with VB code

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sure that the code works with no references to the Interop library. That's the whole point of this question. This whole code is very much easier with any such reference. The intention is to deliver a code which doesn't rely on Interop dll references. It works for that purpose. This question is merely about trying to not use the obsolete method of CreateWrapperOfType

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook is the interop assembly.  If the caller doesn't use it then the GetType() call will fail.  I know what you're asking, just trying to make it easier for you.  I can't think of a way that the code could fail if you don't use CreateWrapperOfType() at all, the late binder doesn't need it.  So just try it without it and tell us what hits the fan.

Comment: If I comment out the line with CreateWrapper, then the line `miAddHandler.Invoke(pSentFolderItems, addHandlerArgs)` fails with
  Message=Object does not match target type. because the ComObject cannot fit as param to the Invocation

Comment: @HansPassant If I comment out the line with CreateWrapper, then the line `miAddHandler.Invoke(pSentFolderItems, addHandlerArgs)` fails with
  "Message=Object does not match target type". Because the ComObject cannot fit as param to the Invocation. I am ultimately trying to dynamically assign to event handler of the Items Class. As you know (because i read many of your posts in past), the dynamic object properties can be used for methods or properties, but not events. I seem to need a wrapped type of 'Items' to pass to the method handler which was created from the event(via Reflection)

Comment: Ah, this is about an event.  Yeah, that's a problem with late binding.  What the synthetic ItemsClass from the interop assembly does is pretend that the class has that event, even though the event interface is not actually implemented by the COM type.  So you have a hard dependency on that assembly, even though you don't want to use it.  Users have found other workarounds for this, find them by googling "vb.net late binding event handler" for hits.

Comment: I'm not fond of what I see so far. i think the best options are 1. Rewrite in C# where the dynamic Items object can have the event handler take a delegate easily - for me this means re-writing the whole thing, as it is a tool which takes one language or the other, and don't want to reference my own dlls either. 2. Use the obsolete method in VB, as this works...

Comment: This method appears to have come out of obsolescence!